# GetFiles using path and pattern while ignoring a certain file name in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get all the .cs files in a certain path. I am doing this using

```
string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern);
```

Where path is a valid folder path and pattern is *.cs. However this also returns AssemblyInfo.cs and i dont want that file to be included although it matches the pattern. I want to ignore all the files with the name AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: whats the problem with just removing the `AssemblyInfo.cs` from the list you got out of the `GetFiles()`?

Comment: How do I do that I am new to C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still need it in an array you can do the following:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern).Where(filename => !filename.EndsWith("AssemblyInfo.cs")).ToArray();
```

If you don't need it as an array then you can leave off the call to `.ToArray()` and that will return an `IEnumerable<string>`.

If you're using a version of .NET that doesn't support Linq (i.e. a version before 3.5) then you can just skip over those parts when you iterate over the array, like so:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern);
foreach (string filename in files)
{
    if (filename.EndsWith("AssemblyInfo.cs"))
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all....I'll figure out why linq was not working... and thanks for giving me all the ideas.

Comment: If you're using v3.5 or v4 and Linq isn't working for you check that you've included `using System.Linq;` where you declare which other namespaces you're using.

Answer (score 3):

Most straightforward way would be:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern).ToList().RemoveAll(f => f.IndexOf("AssemblyInfo.cs", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry assumed you're using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4 - so what Visual Studio and framework you're using? Let me know and I'll update the answer accordingly..

Comment: I am using VS 2010 and .net f/w 4.0

Comment: `IndexOf()` returns an integer, not bool. You have to compare the result of that to 0. And I think you're missing closing parenthesis before `ToArray()`. Also, why are you creating the intermediate list and don't use LINQ instead?

Comment: @svick thanks, syntax error corrected. I gave something bit more readable than LINQ, but agree that Dave answer with pure LINQ is better practice.

Answer (score 2):

there are several options to do that, for example

```
string[] files = (from x in Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern) where !x.EndsWith ("AssemblyInfo.cs") select x).ToArray();
```

Comment: I think GetFiles returns full path.. isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using .NET 3.5 or higher:

```
string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern).Where(o => Path.GetFileName(o).ToLower() != "assemblyinfo.cs").ToArray();
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) I am using vs2010 and .net4.0 and creating a C# console application

Comment: huh? Did you remove `System.Core` project reference by any chance?

Comment: Not sure liho1eye, I am a bit new to C# and Visual Studio. I'll take a look later. Thank you appreciate the quick response.